# Convert yolov3-spp.weights to file.tf model

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, detection, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to convert `yolov3-spp.weights` to `.tf model`.

I found how to convert `yolov3_tiny.weights` and `yolov3.weights`
but I couldn't convert the `yolov3_spp`.

Comment: I gave the answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291138/convert-yolov3-spp-weights-to-tf-model).